# Sort table in descending order

Tags: r, ggpubr

Based on the data and code below, is it possible to sort the table in `descending order`?

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(CITYNAME = c("a", "b", "c", 
    "d", "e", "f", "g", 
    "h", "i", "j", "k", 
    "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", 
    "r", "s", "t", "u", 
    "w", "x", "y", "z"), AvgPpt = c(127.785, 
131.456, 128.357, 114.792, 131.383, 129.696, 137.008, 136.129, 
132.881, 131.676, 129.103, 132.475, 122.263, 132.393, 134.552, 
120.322, 125.987, 132.337, 131.18, 122.705, 123.285, 128.853, 
134.494, 114.154)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
library(ggpubr)

tbl_ppt = df %>%
             ggtexttable(cols = c("Municipilality", "Average Precipitaiton (mm)"),
                  rows = NULL,
                  theme = ttheme("mBlue"))
tbl_ppt
```

Comment: Please don't redundantly add tags to the title. Ideally the question title should form an actual sentence that asks a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `arrange` your data in your desired order before passing it to `ggtexttable`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(desc(AvgPpt)) %>%
  ggtexttable(cols = c("Municipilality", "Average Precipitaiton (mm)"),
              rows = NULL,
              theme = ttheme("mBlue"))
```

[image]